# Magento 2 get transaction status from Braintree

Tags: magento2, braintree

I transaction state is not getting updated at Magento when it changes at Braintree. I manually want to get the transaction status from Braintree but unable to call the Braintree method in my custom module.
Any sugesstion how can I call Braintree method and get the status of transaction?

```
$gateway->transaction()->search([
  Braintree_TransactionSearch::status()->is(Braintree_Transaction::SETTLED)
]);
```

I want to call this method.

Comment: Add what you have untill now

Comment: That is what I  need to know. I have created a helper already but in that I am unable to get the instance of Braintree Adapter.

Answer (score 2):

Somethink like this

```
namespace Vendore\ModuleName\Helper\Braintree;
use Magento\Braintree\Model\Adapter\BraintreeAdapterFactory;
use Magento\Braintree\Model\Adapter\BraintreeSearchAdapter;


class Status extends AbstractHelper {

    private $braintreeAdapterFactory;
    /**
     * @var BraintreeSearchAdapter
     */
    private $braintreeSearchAdapter;

    /**
     * Status constructor.
     * @param BraintreeAdapterFactory $braintreeAdapterFactory
     * @param BraintreeSearchAdapter $braintreeSearchAdapter
     */
    public function __construct(
        BraintreeAdapterFactory $braintreeAdapterFactory,
        BraintreeSearchAdapter $braintreeSearchAdapter
        ) {
        $this->braintreeAdapterFactory = $braintreeAdapterFactory;
        $this->braintreeSearchAdapter = $braintreeSearchAdapter;
    }

    /**
     * @param $transactionId
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function get($transactionId)
    {
        $braintreeAdapter = $this->braintreeAdapterFactory->create();
        $collection = $braintreeAdapter->search(
            [
            $this->braintreeSearchAdapter->id()->is($transactionId)
            ]
            );

        //add some check if we got correct response
        //and  get status
        return $collection->firstItem()->status;
    }
}
```